# Starting point of ios application

Tags: ios, objective-c

if write something in

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

     NSLog(@"Starting point 1");
}
```

**main.m**

```
 int main(int argc,char * argv[])
 {
  ......

  NSLog(@"Starting point 0");
  }
```

Which one is more useful main.m or appDelegate.m one and in which scenerio.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to set initial controller via code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an interesting article that explains the app launch sequence.

http://oleb.net/blog/2011/06/app-launch-sequence-ios/

**As a resume of the article the conclusion is:**

Besides application:`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, there are several more entry points for custom code during the launch sequence (none of which are usually needed):

Directly in `main()` before `UIApplicationMain()` is called.
The init method of a custom UIApplication subclass.
The `initWithCoder:` or awakeFromNib methods of our application delegate if it is created from a NIB file (the default).
The +`initialize` methods of our application delegate class or a custom UIApplication subclass. Any class receives an +initialize message before it is sent its first message from within the program.

**Note** that this sequence only happens at the actual launch of an app. If the app is already running and simply brought back from the background, none of this occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You should use your `UIApplicationDelegate`, **not** the `main.m`.

The *didFinishedLaunching* method is a good (but not the only) starting point.

Only there your are sure all the iOS specific code is loaded correctly.
In the main the load could have had an error, the line would be executed in the main but not in the *didFinishedLaunching* method.

Answer (score 0):

The main() method is the very first thing that is called in terms of iOS applications however it is a general rule never to touch the main() function in iOS programming. 
The 
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
occurs after a successful launch of the app and should be used for any processes you need to do at the start of the application.